# How to create this textured look?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture

[image]

I'm looking to create this textured look for my project. I know how to create textured gradient. But I don't know how to achieve this look for the overall artwork in illustrator. Is it a kind of paper texture or vector texture or just the the grain effect in illustrator?

image from http://www.lottanieminen.com/illustration/meidan-perhe/

Comment: Can you describe exactly what texture? The paper look in the background? There are quite a lot of tutorials around on textured backgrounds and objects in illustrator. Have you tried any? Such as this? http://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/tutorials/adobe-illustrator/texture-techniques-for-vector-artwork/

Comment: the textured background. I tried using different vector textures but I didn't get the effect that I wanted. so I was wondering if it's a specific kind of texture that's needed to create this kind of textured background

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this was created with the default Illustrator grain texture.

If you're only looking to match the overall texture and not the slightly-darker accentuating bars, you can go to Effect > Texture > Grain and set the intensity to a low value.

Comment: If this method isn't what you're looking for, then I would suggest going for one created/edited in Photoshop and overlay on the artwork. Change the blend mode/opacity in the appearance panel to adjust the contrast.

Comment: He's right, the original texture was probably applied with transparency masking. Suggested tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPm5aUkq3OY